# Problem while populating child's id with parent's id in Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

i'm not a professional in spring boot / hibernate jpa, so i apologize in advance.

I have 2 Entities, one called Document and the other called Bgo. Document is the parent table and Bgo the child. So my objective is to create the Document and after that, Bgo will receive it's id, for example:
When i create the first Document, it will have id_document = 1, so after that, the Bgo will have id_document = 1 as well.
I want to populate the child's id with the parent's id.

Here is the Parent Entity:

```
package com.testing.testing.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id_document;

private int num_document;

private Date date;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Bgo bgo;

public Document() {
}

public Document(Bgo bgo) {
    this.id_document = bgo.getId_document();
    this.bgo = bgo;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Bgo getBgo() {
    return bgo;
}

public void setBgo(Bgo bgo) {
    this.bgo = bgo;
}

public long getId_document() {
    return id_document;
}

public void setId_document(long id_document) {
    this.id_document = id_document;
}

public int getNum_document() {
    return num_document;
}

public void setNum_document(int num_document) {
    this.num_document = num_document;
}


}
```

And Child Entity:

```
package com.testing.testing.models;

import java.io.Serializable;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BGO")
public class Bgo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private long id_document;

private String name_bgo;

private int num_bgo;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id_document", referencedColumnName = "id_document")
private Document document;

public Bgo() {
    
}

public Bgo(Document document) {
    this.id_document = document.getId_document();
    this.document = document;
}

public long getId_document() {
    return id_document;
}

public void setId_document(long id_document) {
    this.id_document = id_document;
}

public String getName_bgo() {
    return name_bgo;
}

public void setName_bgo(String name_bgo) {
    this.name_bgo = name_bgo;
}

public int getNum_bgo() {
    return num_bgo;
}

public void setNum_bgo(int num_bgo) {
    this.num_bgo = num_bgo;
}

public Document getDocument() {
    return document;
}

public void setDocument(Document document) {
    this.document = document;
}




}
```

I used the term PrimaryKeyJoinColumn cause i want Bgo's id to be the Document's id, thats why i also used the same name "id_document". So Bgo's id will be Primary and Foreign at the same time (if it is wrong please tell me a better way to do it, knowledge is always welcoming)

I have also Document's Repository:

```
package com.testing.testing.repository;

import com.testing.testing.models.Document;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<Document, Long> {

}
```

And Bgo's:

```
package com.testing.testing.repository;

import com.testing.testing.models.Bgo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BgoRepository extends JpaRepository<Bgo, Long> {

}
```

Document's Controller:

```
package com.testing.testing.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import com.testing.testing.models.Document;
import com.testing.testing.repository.DocumentRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/document")
public class DocumentController {

@Autowired
DocumentRepository documentRepository;


@GetMapping
public List<Document> listDocument() {
    return documentRepository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping
public Document createDocument(@RequestBody Document document) {
    return documentRepository.save(document);
}
}
```

Bgo's Controller:

```
package com.testing.testing.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import com.testing.testing.models.Bgo;
import com.testing.testing.repository.BgoRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/bgo")
public class BgoController {

@Autowired
BgoRepository bgoRepository;

@GetMapping
public List<Bgo> listBgo() {
    return bgoRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

So basically, the problem is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS99h.png)

When i create a new Document and also the Bgo object, Bgo's id is 0, as you can see in the image, the object Bgo has the "id_document = 0 ", shouldn't it be id_document = 1 ?

And when i try to list Bgo, it still shows id_document = 0:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH0RE.png)

That's how i want the database to be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mm0Pf.png)

As you can see, they are different tables. But Document has the primary key and is the parent, and Bgo is a child cause it is receiving Document's id. As you can see, Bgo's has the Document's id, it is primary and foreign at the same time, thats why i used PrimaryKeyJoinColumn. Both of them have the same id, Document's id equals Bgo's id. So whenever i create a Document and a Bgo at the same time, both of them should have the same id.

Comment: Preambles like your first sentence, while pleasant and perfectly natural, are, nevertheless, considered [*non-contextual padding*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142315/should-i-remove-personal-introductions?noredirect=1&lq=1). It will more than likely be edited out by someone at some point. So you might want to consider removing it yourself before anybody else does.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to use the inheritance functionality comes with Spring instead. have a look at this:
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance

you can for instance use the @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
on your parent table. and then you will annotate the child with just the @Entity
and then you will extend it as you normally do in a normal Inheritance scenario
so your parent class will look like so:

```
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Document")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)

public class Document {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Id")
private Integer Id;

@Column(name = "num_document")
private int num_document;

@Column(name = "date")
private Date date;


public Document() {
}


public Document( int num_document, Date date) {
    super();
    this.num_document = num_document;
    this.date = date;
}



}
```

and the child will look like so

```
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bgo")
public class Bgo extends Document {
    @Column(name = "name_bgo")
    private String name_bgo;
    @Column(name = "num_bgo")
    private int num_bgo;

    public Bgo(String name_bgo, int num_bgo) {
        super();
        this.name_bgo = name_bgo;
        this.num_bgo = num_bgo;
    }

    public Bgo() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and you will have One JPARepository which looks like so;

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<Document, Integer> {


}
```

the result of this code, will generate one table in your database with one extra column dtype which will identify the record to be either Bgo or any other type you might need to add in the future. this is the idea behind inheritance anyway

I hope this helped

Comment: and by the way, you only need one repository for both classes

Comment: Can you show in a more beginner way how Document and Bgo would be? Cause how i did, the Bgo is gettind id_document = 2, instead of getting parent's id_document = 1. So i don't know if i did it wrongly or if the Inheritance thing didn't work for me.
My bad

Comment: check now I have edited the answer, by mapping one to one you were doing composition and not inheritance, which is what you need in your case . check this link for more details about the mapping strategies in Spring                                                                        https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: You got it wrong i think. I don't want Bgo's to have num_document and neither date. Bgo has it's own attributes, like name_bgo and num_bgo. Bgo will have the same id from the parent's table. So whenever i create a new Document, the id will be id_document = 1, cause is the first Document i've created, and Bgo will also have the id_document = 1, thats why i'm creating the Document and Bgo at the same time, so while creating Document, its id is going to be populated to Bgo's id as well. It shows in one of the images i posted

Comment: I think I still did not get it, so you want to create a document as a parent, then insert under that document some Bgos, so all the Bgo will be listed under one document ?

Comment: I have edited the answer again, so that in your database you will have only one table called Document and it contains the following attribute  ,[id]  ,[date] ,num_document]
      ,[name_bgo] ,[num_bgo]

Comment: if that is not what you want you are welcome to tell me how would you like to model your database schema and I will guide you how to do it in Spring

Comment: For example:
I have 2 Entities right now, right? But i'll have more later. I made it basic so i could give less work to people when getting replied.
But the main thing is, Document is the Parent table and others tables will all be childs.
Bgo is an example, its a child. So i what want is: i'm creating Document with it's own attributes which is num_document, date and i have the auto increment id, but i want to create Bgo in the same post request as well. Thats why in one of the images its showing how i want it and the problem that im trying to solve as well.

Comment: i'm trying to populate the Parent's id (Document's id) to the child's id( Bgo's id). So whenever i create a Document which has the auto increment id, it will be like id_document = 1, then id_document = 2 and so on. But as you can see in the code, i used the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn in Bgo, cause i want the Bgo to have the id from Document, it will be like a Primary and Foreign key at the same time in Bgo i think. But the problem is, eventho i did all these things, even when i create a Document and then the bgo at the same request, as you can see in the image, bgo's id is still id_documento = 0

Comment: And i want it to be id_document = 1, just like documents id. For example: when i create a document and then a bgo in the same request, i want both to share the same id. So document's id will be 1 and bgo's will be the same. I want Document's id to be the to bgo's id, thats why i used PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.
When i create another document and another bgo at the same request, i want both to have id_document = 2 and so on. Bgo will have the document's id, thats what i want, but eventhough i tried, as you can see in the image, bgo's id is still 0, eventhough i created i document that has id = 1.

Comment: But i thank you very much for trying to help me, eventhough it's taking some time. I appreciate a lot

Comment: I'm reflecting Document's id to Bgo's id. The first Document and Bgo ever created, both of them should have id = 1 both of them should be the same.I literally want that Document's and Bgo's id to be the same, the Parent's Id will reflect into the Child's id.
So whenever i create a Document and a Bgo, i will know that Bgo is comming from the parent Document i just created, cause they will have the same id.

Comment: ok let me ask you this, How many tables do you want to store in your database? do you want to save the parent and the child in the same table ?

Comment: do you mean that you want the child to inherit only the id from the parent,

Comment: But remembering that Document and Bgo, they have their own attributes. They will only share the same id

Comment: Nop, they are different tables. I will save each one in different tables.

Comment: I am not sure if you really have a parent-child relationship here because as far as I understood your explanation it does not sound like so. you might need to make a trigger in the database to generate a shared Id for you and distribute it to both tables if you want to make two tables

Comment: Yes, they will share only the id. i literally have 2 tables right now, Document and Bgo. Document being the parent, so Bgo will have Document's id. Its a relationship between them.

Comment: I will edit my post and show a image of how i want the database

Answer (score 0):

Here are the three different inheritance strategy you have using spring
Single mapping  is the default mapping
And it uses @inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) annotation to the parent class
In this strategy, the parent class is a table and all its children will be specified in a discriminator column in the parent table. The column called dtype and it contain the name of the entity as a value.
Table per the class strategy is similar to the superclass strategy but the superclass is also an entity you need to avoid this one if you want to make so many join queries
Joined table strategy is used the same as above. In this strategy, the subclasses and the superclass will all be tables in the database, but the subclasses will not inherit  the filed of the superclass, it is useful if we want to apply data integrity and null constrains on some field

for more details look here
https://thorben-janssen.com/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/
choose which one will suit your case and then you can use the implementation I provided in the first answer and you only need to change the this annotation
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)

Comment: I just edited my post with an image of how i want the database

Comment: I will have more entities, like Bga and Bir. But all of them follows the same logic, which is Document being the parent, and them having the same id of the parent. I'll create all of them in the same post request, so all of them will have the Document's id.

Comment: it looks like you need the primary key in the document to be a primary and foreign key in the other table. Primary keys always need to be unique, foreign keys need to allow non-unique values if the table is a one-to-many relationship. It is perfectly fine to use a foreign key as the primary key if the table is connected by a one-to-one relationship, not a one-to-many relationship, but I think you are talking about inheritance relationship in your question, which does not make sense to do it the way you want to do it

Comment: I will suggest that you consider having another design to merge these two tables into one table and apply the discriminator approach in the @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) this will make more sense and will be easier to extend you, model, in the future